# How to change add cart button text to backorder text while backorder product?

Tags: magento2

How to change add cart button text to backorder text while backorder product?

I was tried this but not working

```
if($_product->getStockItem()->getBackorders()!=0){
$buttonTitle=$this->__('Backorder');
}
```

Comment: this may help for you. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127243/changing-add-to-cart-button-text-in-magento-2-1-0-overriding-js-file

Comment: Thank ! I got it by below code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
$stockRegistry = $obj->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');
$stockitem = $stockRegistry->getStockItem($_product->getId(),$_product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());

  if($stockitem->getBackorders() == 1):
    $buttonTitle = __('Backorders');
  else:
    $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart');
  endif;

?>
```